# Preserve apostrophes sent in JSON

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending a JSONArray to a server where my script decodes it and uses the data within to update a MYSql database. The problem at the moment is that everything works as it should do until the script encounters a field containing an apostrophe which I understand is used by php as an escape character.

How do I avoid this while still preserving the apostrophe? Do I add something at the Android end and then remove it server side or can I ignore it at the server side while still preserving it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: PHP's escape character is a backslash, apostrophes have been never been used as escapes for PHP. If there's an apostrophe in a json string, then it should itself be escaped with a backslash, e.g. `{"x":"This \" quote is escaped"}`

Comment: If it doesn't work as it is supposed to, what does it do? When does it stop behaving as expected? Parsing JSON? Being inserted into a database? (I'm betting this is [Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) territory). Being pulled out of a database? Are magic_quotes messing about with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, your problem is not that PHP treats the apostrophe as an escape (it doesn't), but that you are not [sanitising your database input](http://bobby-tables.com).

In a MySQL query, an apostrophe has a special meaning (string encapsulator) and the presence of an unescaped apostrophe breaks your SQL syntax.

I don't know which database driver you are using, but you either need one of these:

- [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
- [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

...or better, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanks very much Dave, will give the above a go.